# Codewars snail test fails for empty array

Tags: java, arrays

This is the kata: https://www.codewars.com/kata/snail/train/java

I came up with this code.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Snail {


public static int[] snail(int[][] array) {
ArrayList<Integer> snailArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    int direction = 3;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    if (array.length != 0) {
        while (snailArrayList.size() < array.length * array.length) {
            if (direction == 3) {
                while (y <= array.length - 1 && array[x][y] != -1) {
                    snailArrayList.add(array[x][y]);
                    array[x][y] = -1;
                    y++;
                }
                y--;
                x++;
                direction = 6;
            } else if (direction == 6) {
                while (x <= array.length - 1 && array[x][y] != -1) {
                    snailArrayList.add(array[x][y]);
                    array[x][y] = -1;
                    x++;
                }
                x--;
                y--;
                direction = 9;
            } else if (direction == 9) {
                while (y >= 0 && array[x][y] != -1) {
                    snailArrayList.add(array[x][y]);
                    array[x][y] = -1;
                    y--;
                }
                y++;
                x--;
                direction = 12;
            } else if (direction == 12) {
                while (x > 0 && array[x][y] != -1) {
                    snailArrayList.add(array[x][y]);
                    array[x][y] = -1;
                    x--;
                }
                x++;
                y++;
                direction = 3;
            }
        }
    }
    int[] snailArray = new int[snailArrayList.size()];
    if (snailArray.length != 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < snailArrayList.size(); i++) {
            snailArray[i] = snailArrayList.get(i);
        }
    }
    return snailArray;
} 
}
```

It works fine on my phone, but for some reason it fails to pass the test when an empty array is given. The error I get is:

```
[[]] should be sorted to [].
```

and

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at Snail.snail(Snail.java:15)
at SnailTest.test(SnailTest.java:35)
at SnailTest.SnailTest2Empty(SnailTest.java:62)
```

What's confusing for me is that with an empty array, the program doesn't even enter the `if(array.length != 0)` statement. I'm sure the solution is simple, but I just can't see it. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: My guess is that your code succeeds with an empty array, but fails with an array containing an empty array.

Comment: That's because doing an array.length will return 1 for a multidimensional array. The right way to check would be array[0].length which will return 0.

Comment: Thank you! That was very helpful. My code passes all tests now.

Answer (score -1):

```
if (array[0].Length == 0)
    {
        return new int[0];
    }
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.